# Converting Google Form Responses to Google Sheets as a Viewer

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a way that I am able to convert a list of Google Form Responses to Google Sheets as a viewer? I have permission to view previous responses, but I am not the owner of the forms.

Comment: "convert" how??

Comment: Like I mean make a copy of responses in google sheets

Comment: so just wanted to clarify, does this mean that the responses are saved on the "Responses" tab on docs.google.com/forms, and you would want to copy those responses into Google Sheets, is that correct ?

Comment: I don't own the google forms, but I want to find a way to make a copy of those responses and paste them into google sheets. Best if those responses can be separated by individual users

Comment: @InfinitySwordofDiamond so I just want to make sure once again, you are not the owner of the form, but technically you have Editor Access to the form for you to be able to view those responses, is that true?

Comment: No, I have only the ability to view analytics

Answer (score 0):

if you have View access to the spreadsheet you can create a new spreadsheet:

[sheets.new](https://sheets.new)

and enter this into A1 cell:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL"; "A:Z")
```

where URL is the address of the spreadsheet you have View rights and A:Z is the range you want to import. you can even specify the sheet name like: "Sheet1!A:Z" or "Form Responses1!A:Z"

Comment: I am trying to do a forms that I have permission to view analytics, but it is giving me an error on the google spreadsheet